# Tool to loosen mobile home shower "swivel elbow" connection?

Tags: plumbing, shower, tools, hand-tools, trailer

I have a shower faucet that is spraying out the back of the middle connection (that one that goes up to the shower-head):

[image: back of the shower, where the pipes attach]

I'd like to remove the grey connection (the swivel elbow) so I can see what the washer inside looks like and replace it if needed but the grey end is more than finger tight, I mean I can't loosen it with my fingers alone.

It only has 3 "wings" and it's plastic and I don't want to break it.

I bought a little (6") adjustable wrench but it doesn't feel I'm getting a good grip on it.

Is there a tool that's mean to be used with this swivel elbow end? Seems like this would be easier with the proper tool.

For context, this is in a 1997 Schult mobile home.

The leak drilled a hole in the drywall behind it:

[image: drywall with a hole in it from the water leak]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an online search for Basin Wrench. Available from just about anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! I watched a couple of videos on how to use a Basin Wrench and was able to unscrew the end with my fingers, putting even pressure on all 3 wings. Your reply was helpful!  :)

Comment: The black band around the feed line looks like it has some corrosrion on it.  Could that be the source of the leak?

Comment: Or, John, it's the result of some hardness in the water settling on the fittings after the water has sprayed around then evaporated. I see white marks on at least 2 of those crimp rings.

Comment: The water was spraying out from the grey/brass parts, below the black band.

Comment: I am planning to replace the middle hose, complete with ends. I got the bottom end free but the top end disappears into a case that is held down with square-hole screws.  Hoping to buy a square screwdriver today so I can open the case and get the shower hose out to replace it.